# How to get the bounding box of a wrapping inline element with prototype

Tags: javascript, dom, prototypejs

I used to use cumulativeOffset() and getDimensions() to calculate the bounding box of elements, but just realized that cumulativeOffset returns the top left corner oft the **start** of an element. Meaning: if an inline element wraps, and the next line is more to the left than the start, I get a displaced bounding box.

After researching a bit, I found that I can use getClientRects() to get all rects. I could then go through, and just take the left position of the rect that's most to the left.

I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this... I just didn't find a boundingBox() prototype function. Did I overlook it?

Edit: I also just found out that getClientRects() is not supported by all browser, so this is no solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a boundingBox() function either, but I wonder if using the same technique ([`cumulativeOffset()`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/cumulativeoffset) and [`getDimensions()`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/getdimensions)) on the parent via: [`getOffsetParent()`](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/getoffsetparent) would do what you want. `getOffSetParent()`:

> "Returns element’s closest positioned
>   ancestor. If none is found, the body
>   element is returned."

Which should account for word-wrapping where the second line is further left.

Comment: Well, if I have a div, and multiple spans inside, and just the last span in the second line wraps, thus becoming a two liner (and creating a third line), the parent information doesn't help me, does it?

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding the issue. It seems like, if the inline spans are within the **parent**, then the parents bounds hold sway even if the `span` ends up odd sized. 

Do you have a url featuring the HTML and CSS you are using for this?

Comment: Here ist a link where I try to demonstrate the problem:
http://test.opentip.org/inlineSpanProblem.php
My main goal, is in fact, to get the right border of any element. I don't see any other way than getting the left position and adding the width.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of a way to do this.  You could set it position:relative, drop a 1x1 absolutely positioned div into it, position it right:0, get that div's LEFT + WIDTH, and subtract the offset width of the original inline item from that value.

Saying that, total hack, maybe you need to rethink the reason you want to do this!

Comment: Mh, this is actually a pretty good idea!
I'll test it, and will come back as soon as it's done.

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by dfitzhenry seems not working in the case of multiline inline elements.
Here's my Javascript solution : get your inline element nextSibling, check if it is an inline element, otherwise create a new inline element, add it to your inline element's parent and then get its offsetLeft:

```
 var parentContainer = inline_elm.parentNode;
 var nextsib = inline_elm.nextSibling;
 var remove_next_sibling = false;
 if(!nextsib || nextsib.clientWidth != 0){
     remove_next_sibling = true;
     var temp= document.createElement('span');
     parentContainer.insertBefore(temp, nextsib);
     nextsib = temp;
 }

 var inline_bounding_right = nextsib.offsetLeft;
 if(remove_next_sibling)    parentContainer.removeChild(nextsib);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but the standard method now to get a bounding box is [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), which is supported in all major browsers and has had [at least partial support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=getboundingclientrect) since 2009 in most browsers. Enjoy!

P.S. [`getClientRects()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getClientRects) is also very useful for getting the individual bounding boxes of the wrapped text. It seems to have the same browser support as `getBoundingClientRect()`, since the one depends on the other, and [this source](http://help.dottoro.com/ljxsdaqk.php) suggests that it's well supported.